# How can I write the from buffer to EEPROM ( as per the following code )?

Tags: c, buffer, i2c, master-slave, eeprom

- struct devices *address - Address of the register.
- number_bytes - number of byte of data to be written.
- int8_t wdata - data to be written to the register address.
- unsigned char *result_buffer - pointer to a buffer of 256 bytes.
- var is defined as *var, which can be used to store the i2c_write(address,1,wdata, the_buffer) to it.
- returns a value instead of 0 or 1.
- For example - (0x2,1, 02, ?).

```
int i2c_buffer_write(struct devices *address, int number_bytes, int8_t wdata, unsigned char *result_buffer)
{
   char *var;
   char the_buffer[256];
   var = i2c_write(address,1,wdata, the_buffer);
   return var;
}

int i2c_new_write()
{
 //How can I write from the buffer to the function i2c_new_write() ?
}
```

How can I put the result_buffer such that I can write from the buffer in i2c_buffer_Write to i2c_new_Write??

Comment: You should use I2c driver provided with the hardware /or OS drivers .if you write it for a controller you have to tell us about which controller you use?

Comment: @Ibram Reda , I use linux and ARM compiler.

Comment: Most of the eeprom chips are supported by a corresponding driver (at24 or at25). Are you trying to repeat them on the studying purposes?